# Ruby: Parsing time from a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to pass an array of times kept as strings (`["08:00:00", "18:00:00"]`) and return them in a more readable manner via a helper method.

However, I keep receiving an argument error in the helper method. This is very odd to me, because if I remove the `Time.parse(time_slot)` and simply try to convert the time using `time_slot.strftime("%I:%M %p")` it throws an error `` undefined method `strftime' for "08:00:00":String ``. The object is clearly being passed in - am I not understanding something?

> line 4: hours <<  Time.parse(time_slot).strftime("%I:%M %p")
>   no time information in ""

Code:

```
1: - I18n.t('date.day_names').each do |day|
2:   - %w[starts ends].each_with_object([]) do |time_type, to_return|
3:     - @hours = to_return << @facility.access_hours["#{time_type}_#{day.downcase}"]
4:   - @hours.compact.tap do |hours|
5:     = day
6:     = hours
7:     = time_helper(hours)
8:     = byebug
(byebug) hours = ["08:00:00", "18:00:00"]
(byebug) time_helper(hours) = "08:00 AM - 06:00 PM"
```

Helper method

```
def time_helper(time)
  hours = []
  time.each do |time_slot|
    hours <<  Time.parse(time_slot).strftime("%I:%M %p")
  end
  hours.join(' - ')
end
```

Comment: `no time information in ""` indicates that the string you're passing to `Time.parse` is empty. Double check that you're passing the data you think you are.

Comment: Somehow you're storing an empty string in `@hours`. Try pushing to `to_return` only if the value isn't an empty string. Also move @hours outside the each_with_object block.

Comment: change `@hours.compact` to `@hours.reject(&:blank?)`. This will remove empty strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is very odd to me, because if I remove the Time.parse(time_slot) and simply try to convert the time using time_slot.strftime("%I:%M %p") it throws an error undefined method `strftime' for "08:00:00":String. The object is clearly being passed in - am I not understanding something?

`time_helper` is being called with an Array like `["08:00:00", "", "18:00:00"]`.

`"08:00:00"` is parsed, but then `Time.parse` chokes on the `""`. If you try `time_slot.strftime("%I:%M %p")` `strftime` errors on `"08:00:00"` because it is a String, not a Time.

You can fix this as PGiII suggests by using [`@hours.reject(&:blank?)`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-reject) which will remove [`nil` as well as empty strings](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F). Although you may still want to figure out why `@facility.access_hours` has blanks in it.